# Updating State with componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I am looking at someone else code who updated the state of object in the react lifecyle:componentWillReceiveProps. I am fairly new to react and redux but thought that you do all the updating of state in the reducer useless its local state. Can someone tell me why he is doing it in componentWillReceiveProps? Thanks

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.isEditingbook && !nextProps.isEditingbook) {
      let book = this.props.index.bookDictionary[this.props.currentbook.id] 
      book.name = this.state.model.name.value
    }
    this.setState({ ...this.state, ...nextProps})
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, `componentWillrecieveProps` has been deprecated because it might cause some problems, take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) . Instead, React docs point out that you should use `componentDidUpdate` which is a safe-to-use method.

And answering your question, if you looked a code where that person was using redux, then he used that deprecated method because when you bind a component to redux goblal state (store) through `mapStateToProps`, it's properties are bind to that component props. So, in other words, whenever the global state changes so does the component props, and if you want to "track" these changes in your component logic, you have to know when it's props are going to change, that's why you use `componentWillRecieveProps` or `componentDidUpdate` methods.

Here is how that example code should has been done with `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { //prevProps is the previous props of the component before being updated
   //so, if this.props != prevProps it means that component props have been updated

    if(this.props.isEditingbook && !prevProps.isEditingbook) {
      let book = this.props.index.bookDictionary[this.props.currentbook.id] 
      book.name = this.state.model.name.value
    }
    this.setState({ ...this.state, ...prevProps})
  }
```

Comment: I am aware that the componentWillrecieveProps has been deprecated thanks. I tried doing it the way you suggested and i get an error Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. To me it makes alot more sense do change the redux state in the reducer but i am very new to this.

Comment: No, you must not update it within the reducer, probably you even can't do that. `componentDidUpdate` is also triggered when the state is updated, so, if you call a `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` you have to validate it, and be sure that `setState` is invoked ONLY when the right conditions are set, otherwise `componentDidUpdate` will be triggered again and again until you have that error

Comment: If you are new to react, I suggest you NOT using redux, using them together is not easy for novices. If you're not, then I suggest you to take a better look into redux itself, and try to completely understand how it works before implementing it along with react. Take a look [here](https://redux.js.org/basics)